# Inputs con datos devueltos por el servidor

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando vue + axion + bootstrap y quiero hacer unos formularios.
Declaro unos inputs con la clase v-model como este:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="user" class="control-label col-md-2">Nombre</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
<input v-model="Usuario_Nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="su nombre" />
</div>
</div>
```

en los que quiero que salgan los datos devueltos por el servidor.
Creo el script para conectar al servidor y recoger los datos.
En el vue script declaro:

```
data: {
  datos: [],
  Usuario_Nom: '',
  Usuario_xxx: '',
   ... 
  }
```

y en el then

```
this.datos = response.data;
this.Usuario_Nom = this.datos.Usuario.Nombre;
this..... //El resto de datos del formulario
```

Todo esto lo ejecuto pulsando un botón como este

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="btEnviar" v-on:click="getUsuarios(user.value,pass.value)">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Todo esto se ejecuta y funciona pero no se guardan los datos en los inputs. Realmente sí se guardan pero durante una fracción de segundo y desaparecen, como si la pagina se recargase.

¿Alguna idea de porqué ocurre esto?

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo donde invoca una peticion y los resultados los muestra en el html https://jsbin.com/jeqekexiqa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Tegito. Eso funciona cuando cargas la pagina, pero el problema lo tengo con la pagína ya cargada y ejecutando el script desde un botón